# Is there a way to download the full history from GitHub?

Tags: git, github

I have just started using GitHub, and after making a few changes to some files in my repository, I downloaded the repository as a zip file. I get only the latest versions of all the files there. I can see the history online, however. Is there a way to get all the versions I contributed in a zip file?

Comment: When you made your changes, did you clone the repository in local (on your computer) ?

Comment: No, I didn't. Should I have?

Comment: In that case, follow @DVG 's answer. To show the history, either use a visual git client or run `git log --oneline --graph --decorate`

Comment: Thank you! I will try this.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Github is a site that hosts git repositories. The download as ZIP feature isn't for getting a local copy of the repository, it just downloads the view of the repository that you are viewing at that time (the master branch, for example). This is more for getting a specific version of the software.

If you wish to contribute to the repository, you should instead be cloning using the git command line tool:

```
git clone https://github.com/someuser/some-repo.git
```

This gives you a copy of the repository. A complete copy, histroy and all. You would then interact with the repository on your local machine, and push and pull changes as allowed by the permissions on github.

Typically, you'll actually fork a repository to your account, and push and pull changes to that copy, and then send the original repo a pull request when you want your changes to be included in the primary version.